# Count repetitions of a variable length sequence across data subsets

Tags: r

Answers or points in the right direction are appreciated.

-I have a dataset that is organized by group (id)
-There is a column (trial) that indicates the trial the data corresponds to. This value is repeated from 1 to some number. Each trial value can be repeated a variable length (e.g., 1122234444). 
-Sequences through the trial values are repeated within group. E.g., within each id - you go through a sequence of trial and then trial restarts at 1 and goes through the sequence again for some number of times.

I need to know how many times the trial sequence has been repeated within each group of id.

The desired output is the variable "repetition".

The "repetition" variable should start at 1 and repeat until the sequence restarts again to 1, where it should move to 2 to indicate that the trial sequence is on it's 2nd repeat.

The max number of trials, ids, and the number of repetitions are always variable, but the trial sequence always goes (repeating at variable length) 1,2,3,....

```
id <- sort(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4, times = 2))
trial <- rep(1:2, each = 2 , times = 2)
repetition <- rep(1:2, each = 4, times = 2)

df <- data.frame(id, trial, repetition)

   id trial repetition
1   a     1          1
2   a     1          1
3   a     2          1
4   a     2          1
5   a     1          2
6   a     1          2
7   a     2          2
8   a     2          2
9   b     1          1
10  b     1          1
11  b     2          1
12  b     2          1
13  b     1          2
14  b     1          2
15  b     2          2
16  b     2          2
```

Comment: There seems to be a need for another column or a different accounting of repetition as row 1: a 1 1 is not actually repeating any prior 1, so could be 0. If row 1: a 1 1, then it would seem that row 2: a 1 2, if what is meant by repetition is a repetition of trial 1. But I have to guess that what is meant by trial here is a repetition of something going on within a linear experiment chain and it is actually a different trial, with the same stimulus repeated. Me, I'd number trials sequentially, and account for stim & such  in three other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your data looks something like this:

```
trial=rep(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7),2)
id=c(rep("a",length(trial/2)),rep("b",length(trial/2)))
df=data.frame(id,trial,repetition=numeric(length(trial)))
```

Then this code does what you are asking for as far as I understood:

```
counter=1
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  if(i>1){
    if(df$id[i-1] != df$id[i]){
      counter=1
    } else {

      if(df$trial[i-1]>df$trial[i]){
        counter=counter+1
      }

    }  
    df$repetition[i]=counter
  }else{
    df$repetition[i]=1
  }
}
```

In my data-frame the `repetition`-column already exists but
this also works if the data-frame `df` doesn't have the `repetition`-column yet.
It will be added by the code in the loop if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This works great - thank you! I had tried to implement something similar previously that looked for the difference across rows to trigger the reset but had struggled with some of the syntax. Thanks for showing me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using `dplyr` together with `splitstackshape`. We first use `new = cumsum(c(1, diff(trial) != 0))` to get the number of different groups. We then group by `id`, `new` and count them (`new1`). We `slice` to get the top of each group and use `cumsum(trial == 1)` to get the repetition. Finally, we use `splitstackshape` function `expandRows` which replicates the rows by the count number we obtained from `new1`. We finish by tidying a bit with `select` and `ungroup`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = cumsum(c(1, diff(trial) != 0))) %>% 
  group_by(id, new) %>% 
  mutate(new1 = n()) %>% 
  slice(1L) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(repetition = cumsum(trial == 1)) %>% 
  expandRows('new1') %>% 
  select(-new) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 16 × 3
#       id trial repetition
#   <fctr> <int>      <int>
#1       a     1          1
#2       a     1          1
#3       a     2          1
#4       a     2          1
#5       a     1          2
#6       a     1          2
#7       a     2          2
#8       a     2          2
#9       b     1          1
#10      b     1          1
#11      b     2          1
#12      b     2          1
#13      b     1          2
#14      b     1          2
#15      b     2          2
#16      b     2          2
```

Comment: Also works - thank you! I wasn't familiar with the library splitstackshape, thanks for showing it to me. As a note, this solution clocks in faster than the previous answer, which might matter for larger datasets.